# Unable to initialize an App using Expo - Following is the error shown in the terminal

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1088   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module
> 'C:\Users\PCNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-c
> li\bin\expo.js' ←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:108 5:15)←[39m ←[90m    at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:27)←[39m
> ←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
> (internal/modules/run_ma in.js:60:12)←[39m ←[90m    at
> internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {   code:
> ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,   requireStack: [] }

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your server and simulator, or write npm install

Comment: Did this already, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Clean your cache (delete app in phone or clean cache) and restart the server, should fix this answer your problem.